# Django model should be bi-directional (?)

Tags: django-models

I have started looking into Django more closely, recently and thus started to create a vocabulary learning app, in which people will be asked to specify which language to learn etc.

Right now, people can add a Word via the admin-backend that consists of language, translation, Word:
[image]

Now, I have the result looking like this:

<QuerySet [<WordTranslation: 3 Morgen, Bahasa Indonesia: Pagi >]>

3: ID, Morgen (german word), Bahasa Indonesia (language to learn): Pagi (word meaning in said language).

This is my models.py:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word


class WordTranslation(models.Model):
    vocabulary = models.ForeignKey(Word, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    translation = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.pk} {self.vocabulary}, {self.language}: {self.translation} '

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['vocabulary', 'language', 'translation']
```

I want to be able to switch between languages easily, but since I'd have to setup every word translation as an extra word for now, I am stuck with adding every word twice but with the translation and vocabulary changed...

(I have two specific users in mind: nativa bahasa indonesia and native German, learning the exact opposite language, but it somehow doesn't make sense to add each word twice. )
I want to avoid hardcoding languages, thus having translation_id, and translation_de is not really a permanent solution. (not implemented at the moment, but it's only a few lines of code)

Is there an easy way to modify the model to allow me to easily switch between languages:
this is a Detail.html:)

`<h1> What does <span style="color:red;">{{ vocabulary }}</span> mean in <span style="color:green;">{{ language }}?</span></h1>`

(vocabulary outputs Morgen and language gives Bahasa Indonesia)

I want to be able to get roughly the following:

`<h1> What does <span style="color:red;">{{ depending on status Morgen or Pagi }}</span> mean in <span style="color:green;">{{ Bahasa Indonesia or German }}?</span></h1>`

I feel like updating the model to fromLanguage and toLanguage does not solve my problem, since I want to be able to switch back and forth. ManyToManyField might work, but I couldn't get it working

Any hints or would this be the best solution for that?
It should, ideally, be expandable to allow n languages, so that I can easily add "support for another language" (i.e. add a language in the admin-site and then populate the model accordingly)

For now, the training purposes the current model works, but I want to be sure to not hit a wall again, any help? :-)

further context:

How can I get a model that allows sth. like the screenshot:
[image]

but for every "language" specified" (iedally the languages are added via languages + (on the left side) and then automatically create a "language-field" and offer a translation.
(or the field "Translation" gets the name of the language)

Comment: How do you enter each word twice? Do you want to only translate from/to German, or from any to any language?

Comment: from and to each language that I want to be able to add. I.e. A user clicks on "de -> indo" he get's the german options in detail and if he/she clicks "indo -> de" they get the indo option and have to enter German. 
Extra points if it works with me adding random languages later on, so that "language a -> language b" works the same as "language-x -> language y" , etc ...
as for entering each word twice: 
put in morgen, bahasa indonesia, pagi and then pagi, german, morgen in the admin